# Changing the value/file of output_stream dynamically in tf.print?

Tags: tensorflow, audio, stream, wav

I am doing some processing on wave audio files using Tensorflow
and saving them using the `tf.print` with `output_stream` option.

```
pcm =contrib_audio.encode_wav(processed_audio,16000)
tf.print(output_stream="file:///tmp/test.wav",summarize=-1)
```

The problem is that I am not able to change value of `/tmp/test.wav` dynamically 
so that multiple wave files are stored.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I tried to improve the formatting of your post, let me know whether it helps, please.

Answer (score -1):

Kindly refer to the below code.

```
# Using a counter
for i in range(1,10):
   fname = "test_"+str(i)+".wav" #filename
   path = "//content/sample_data/" #path to save
   fname = "file://{path}{fname}".format(fname=fname, path = path)
   tf.print(output_stream=fname,summarize=-1)
```

You can create a dynamic text, for it to be a unique filename.

Comment: Still its constant , fname should change over training/inference.

Comment: Hi @AlokPrasad, I updated the code for much easier reproduction.